# How to properly set up this Sage Cell Server?

Tags: python, cell, sage

I have a question regarding the Sage Cell Server. It is a relatively general question, I don't have any code that I need fixed.

I am trying to set up a server but I am finding the world of servers confusing. I've worked plenty with Java and JavaScript, HTML and CSS on frontend stuff, but for the backend Sage server I decided to develop I figured Python was a good choice. Some basic Lynda tutorials and a book later, I have a pretty good idea how python works... But am still lost. My question is basically this:

-**I am trying to design a very simple server running an instance of Sage. I want to be able to SEND Sage code to it (NOT PYTHON) and have it evaluated and the result sent back, as if I were running sage on my own computer. Example: Sending "integrate(x,x)" to the server would return 1/2*x^2**
-**What is the best way to go about doing this? Should I download the Sage Cell Server?**
-**Will I need to even write Python code for this? How long would this task take in hours?**
-**Would it be easier for me to design the server to receive and execute Python code instead of Sage code? How would I go about doing this?**

If you are wondering *why* I want to do this, I want to design a website where people can type in their math problems and have them evaluated by sage. I know there are simpler ways to do this but I've wanted to do server-side work and get people talking with a server for a while now and this seems like a good introduction to it.

Any and all advice is appreciated, resources, help, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are certainly a number of people who have successfully set up their own [Sage cell server](http://sagecell.sagemath.org/static/about.html), and as such things go I hear it is definitely doable.  The previous "simple server" API is pretty much [defunct](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sage-notebook/11oPFsETf9U) and the Sage cell is a pretty reasonable way to do this.  I don't see why you would need to have reinvent the wheel here, and asking on sage-support@googlegroups.com is a logical next step for you.